# How do I insert data retrieved from database into pre-styled HTML tags?

Tags: php, html, database, styling

I want to display the data I retrieve from a database table in styled HTML.
Please look at the code below, the commented out line works and I would like to fill in the data in the `<section class="profile">` below the comment.
Thanks in advance

I know my code is vulnerable, but I want to get it to work before I worry about security.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="menu">
    <?php require('inc-nav.php') ?>

    <section class="content">

        <?php
        require('connect.php');

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $sql = "SELECT name, breed, age FROM dogs";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($dogs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
//          echo 'Name: ' . $dogs['name'] . '<br>' . 'Breed: ' . $dogs['breed'] . '<br>' . 'Age: ' . $dogs['age'] . '<br><hr>';
                echo '
                <section class="profile">
                    <figure class="profile-pic"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                    <h1 class="name">Name</h1>
                    <h2 class="description1">Breed | gender | age</h2>
                    <p class="description2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto corporis dolores dolorum eaque eum in nemo quos totam ullam. Autem?</p>
                    <button class="cta-profile"><a href="#">Read more</a></button>
                </section>
                ';
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>

    </section>

    <?php require('inc-footer.php');?>
</div>
```

Comment: You have all the code there, what have you tried?

Comment: What is your code vulnerable for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want like this

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="menu">
    <?php require('inc-nav.php') ?>

    <section class="content">

        <?php
        require('connect.php');

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $sql = "SELECT name, breed, age FROM dogs";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($dogs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

             ?>
                <section class="profile">
                    <figure class="profile-pic"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                    <h1 class="name"><?php echo 'Name: ' .$dogs['name']; ?></h1>
                    <h2 class="description1"> <?php echo 'Breed: ' . $dogs['breed']; ?>  | gender | <?phpecho  'Age: ' . $dogs['age']; ?></h2>
                    <p class="description2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto corporis dolores dolorum eaque eum in nemo quos totam ullam. Autem?</p>
                    <button class="cta-profile"><a href="#">Read more</a></button>
                </section>
                <?php
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>

    </section>

    <?php require('inc-footer.php');?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo '
               <section class="profile">
                    <figure class="profile-pic"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                    <h1 class="name">'.$dogs["name"].'</h1>
                    <h2 class="description1">'.$dogs["breed"].' | '.$dogs["age"].'</h2>
                    <p class="description2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto corporis dolores dolorum eaque eum in nemo quos totam ullam. Autem?</p>
                    <button class="cta-profile"><a href="#">Read more</a></button>
                </section>
                ';
```